# MS Access VBA DoCmd.TransferText How to Separate Columns?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

The following line should import a semi-colon `;` delimited `.csv` text file to a table.

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, SpecificationName:=specNote, TableName:="tblImport", FileName:="K:\path\file.csv"
```

However this puts all the fields in one field.

What is going wrong here?

Any suggestions?

I specified

- File format: Delimited
- Field delimiter: `;`

I set this through the import wizard and saved this specification. With the wizard all went good.

I want to share the specification but I dont know how to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Share the import specification. That's where it's specified if your file is semicolon-delimited or comma-delimited.

Comment: It's semicolon-delimited

Comment: And where have you specified that in the import specification? As said, share the import specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `specNote` a variable or the name of your specification?

If the latter, try:

```
DoCmd.TransferText _
TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
SpecificationName:="specNote", _
TableName:="tblImport", _
FileName:="K:\path\file.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick, I forgot the parentheses. Shame on me...

Comment: @RudiBloes You're welcome (I'm assuming you meant double-quotes, not parentheses). Please mark my answer as the solution if it answered your question, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the open questions.

Comment: Yes of course. I mix up languages sometimes. “Entre parentheses” Thanks again. I marked the answer.